# Flex 4 iFrame open url internal network to an external network?

Tags: java, apache-flex, iframe, flex4

I need help with a question that I could not answer yet.

I have the following scenario:

One application Java EE / Flex 4 running on a tomcat, inside my Flex layer I have a iFrame passing a url to an ip of my internal network (`http://192.168.1.195:8080/webvisu.htm`) which is another application running within an industrial PLC.

When access this app from within my internal network works fine, but when I try to access this iFrame to an external network in my home for example have a timeout error on `http://192.168.1.195:8080/webvisu.htm`.

I believe this error occurs because the flex client is trying to run this url as I was in a internal network.

Is there any way to run this url from an external network?

Possible solutions:
Some setting on my Tomcat?
A crossdomain.xml file?

I've googled a lot about this problem, but found no solution = (

Sorry for my english I'm using the google translator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

192.168.1.* is not a public IP address.  The only way you'll be able to access it is if you have your home network connected to the other network over VPN; or if you have a web server set up on your local network which is running on the same  IP address.

The use of domain names are supposed to address the problem of accessing IPs directly; but if you're accessing a non-publcly accessible app, you're kind of stuck.

On my current project, for example, the dev server uses an IP Address and the QA server uses a IP address.  Neither of these apps are accessible outside the network.  I have to connect via VPN to access them.

The production server; however; uses a domain name.